# Group, map & reduce with two different reducer-operators

Tags: scala, mapreduce, information-retrieval

I have these tuples:

```
("T1",2,"x1"),
("T1",2,"x2"),
// … etc
```

And i want to reduce it to `("T1", 4, List("x1", "x2"))`. How can i do this ?

I did something like `.group(_._1).map{case (key,list) => key-> list.map(_._2).reduce(_+_)}`
But this is not working, and just sums the numbers without appending the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `groupMapReduce`:

```
val xs = List(
  ("T1",40,"x1"),
  ("T1",2,"x2"),
  ("T2",58,"x3")
)

println(xs.groupMapReduce(_._1)
  (e => (e._2, List(e._3)))
  ({ case ((x, y), (z, w)) => (x + z, y ++ w)})
)
```

with `groupBy`:

```
val xs = List(
  ("T1",40,"x1"),
  ("T1",2,"x2"),
  ("T2",58,"x3")
)
println(xs.groupBy(_._1)
  .view
  .mapValues(ys => (ys.view.map(_._2).sum, ys.map(_._3)))
  .toMap
)
```

If you want to do it in one pass per list, and not use `++` you could try sth. like this:

```
xs.groupBy(_._1)
  .view
  .mapValues(ys =>
     ys.foldRight((0, List.empty[String])){
       case ((_, n, x), (sum, acc)) => (n + sum, x :: acc)
     }
  )
  .toMap
```

All three variants give

```
Map(T2 -> (58,List(x3)), T1 -> (42,List(x1, x2)))
```

Note that combining many lists with `++` might become very inefficient if the number of lists becomes large. It depends on your use-case whether this is acceptable or not.

Answer (score 1):

Using `foldLeft`

```
val tuples = List(
  ("T1",2,"x1"),
  ("T1",2,"x2"),
  ("T2",2,"x1"),
  ("T2",2,"x2"),
  ("T3",2,"x1")
)

tuples.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, (Int, List[String])]){ (acc, curr) =>
  acc.get(curr._1).fold(acc + (curr._1 -> (curr._2, List(curr._3)))) { case (int, ls) =>
    acc + (curr._1 -> (int + curr._2, (curr._3 :: ls).reverse))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have **cats** in scope, all you need to do is this:

```scala
import cats.data.Chain
import cats.syntax.all._

def combineTripletes(data: List[(String, Int, String)]): Map[String, (Int, List[String])] =
  data.foldMap {
    case (key, i, str) =>
      Map(key -> (i, Chain.one(str)))
  } fmap {
    case (sum, chain) =>
      sum -> chain.toList
  }
```